# Get hasLongitude with Yago

Tags: sparql, semantics, virtuoso

I want to get the latitude and longitude of London with a query like the one below
but it doesn't work:

```
PREFIX e: <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/hasLatitude>
SELECT DISTINCT ?long ?lat 
FROM <http://yago-knowledge.org>
 WHERE {
    e:London yago:hasLatitude ?long.
    e:London yago:hasLongitude ?lat. }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The prefix should be `e: <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/>` so that `e:hasLatitude` expands to `http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/hasLatitude`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace that you are using has `hasLatitude`. A namespace is only a URI and has to be general. Try the following query:

```
PREFIX yago: <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?long ?lat 
    FROM <http://yago-knowledge.org>
    WHERE {
        yago:London yago:hasLatitude ?long.
        yago:London yago:hasLongitude ?lat. 
    }
```